# FileInfo.LastWriteTime might be misleading. Any other approach?

Tags: .net

I used FileInfo.LastWriteTime to know when was the exact last time where a certain file, let's say "c:\temp\test_file.txt" was changed.

It works great when someone is actually opens the file, make changes and then save - the FileInfo.LastWriteTime for this path is being updated with the time the file was changed.

But what happens in the following scenario:

Copy a file with the same name but with different content from other location on disc, and paste it in the "c:\temp\" folder (override the existing file) - the file "c:\temp\test_file.txt" was actually changed (overridden by a file with the same name but with different content), *but* the LastWriteTime of the file "c:\temp\test_file.txt" is not the time on which it was overridden, but it is actually the "LastWriteTime" of the file which we copied, and might be significantly earlier then the moment in which it was overridden.

In case I need to know the moment in which the file was overridden, is there any other way, and please **don't** suggest solutions like registering on FileChange events - I'm searching for a solution in which I don't have to keep a program running all the time like a service - my application may not be executed all the time, and I need to know when the file was overridden even if this moment was when my application was closed.

Comment: I tagged this with .NET, but you may want to add a tag for the appropriate language. People search and filter questions by tags, so you'll probably get better answers. I'm assuming C# or VB, but I'm not sure which based on the current content of your question.

Comment: Do you really want to know when the file was changed, or do you actually want to know IF the file was changed?

Comment: Hi Dialecticus, I atually, I want to know IF the file was changed, but now that I said it you'll probably start giving me solutions like: "Save a copy of the file in a side directory, and just compare the current file to the one you have kept aside - that won't help me since I'm watching many many files!! and storing all of them aside is space & time consuming. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Liorp Enigmativity suggested using hash instead of time stamp. Hash will give you a string that is different if the file is different. Length of the hash is 8 bytes for CRC64, or 20 bytes for full blown SHA-1, so it's relatively short.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the advice, but I'm afraid that hash won't help in my situation (unless I misunderstood). Correct me if I'm wrong, you're suggesting that for each file on the folder I'm dealing with I have a table which maps file path into its last known hash code. BUT, there's a chance (even a good one) that two files which are different get the same hashcode. So for each file, if the hashcode is the different then I know they are different, but even if their hash codes are the same, I still need to check if they're different (the last revision and the current revision).Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just use SHA-1 or SHA-512 and don't worry about it. Study hashes more if you like, but know that hash function is the solution to your problem. The chance of hash collision is less that the chance of something catastrophic will happen in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

In the circumstance that you describe in your question you can use the file creation time as this will change when you copy a file.

I suggest that you will need to check both the last write time and the file creation time to determine most changes.

Otherwise you could look at file size, and if that's not sufficient, then you'll need to generate a hash on the file contents.

*edit*

If you are using a `FileInfo` object you need to call the `Refresh` method to update any of the last write time, create time, file exists, etc, properties.

Comment: Hi Enigmatifity,

It doens't work. The FileInfo.CreationTime does not correspond with the moment of the paste (overriden) operation, but is earlier than that.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks at Advanced!

Comment: Hi Enigmatifity, I read your 'edit' and tried to call the FileInfo.Refresh() method before looking at the last write, access and creation time, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use **FileInfo .CreationTime()** & as well as **FileInfo .LastWriteTime()**  methods combination for check.